# 400 Bad Request when doing a Parse Unity cloud call to user.logIn in Parse.Cloud.Define

Tags: authentication, unity-game-engine, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

When trying to define a Parse Cloud Code server side function to handle login I get 400 Bad Request when I try to call it. When I look at the Parse logs it records the error "Failed with: ReferenceError: user is not defined". But the user is definitely defined!

Below is the definition of the cloud code for LogIn:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("LogIn", function(request, response)
{

    user.logIn(request.params.username, request.params.password,
    {
        success: function(user)
        {
            response.success(
            {
                "success": "Log in successful."
            });
        },
        error: function(user, error)
        {
            // We must respond with a success in order to access the
            // result of the request inside Unity.
            response.success(
            {
                "error": "Log in failed.",
                "code": error.code,
                "message": error.message
            });
        }
    });
});
```

From Unity I make this call to the LogIn coud code function:

```
ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync<Dictionary<string, object>> ("LogIn", userInfo).ContinueWith (t =>
{
  etc.....
}
```

I get the following error logged in the server side Parse logs when I call the above from Unity using user sashas123 and also student123:

> E2014-09-26T17:06:18.001Z] v8: Ran cloud function LogIn with:   Input:
>   {"username":"sashas123","password":"test"}   Failed with:
>   ReferenceError: user is not defined
>       at main.js:43:5
>
> E2014-09-26T17:38:50.474Z] v10: Ran cloud function LogIn with:
>   Input: {"username":"student123","password":"test"}   Failed with:
>   ReferenceError: user is not defined
>       at main.js:43:5

The following snapshot from the Data Browser shows that the above users are definitely defined:

![Parse User class][1]

Is there any issue with calling user.LogIn on the server side through Cloud Code or is this a Unity issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like user.logIn should be request.user.logIn :)

I find it's best to handle the case where the function may be called without a logged in user too:

```
if (request.user.logIn != null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    response.error("This function must be called with a logged in user!");
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Also, are you aware Parse provides an API for creating a user already? Have a look at it [here](https://parse.com/docs/unity_guide#users-signup) :)